# Create JSON object starting from another JSON Object for Materialize Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, materialize

I'm trying to work with autocomplete from Materialize.

The API Request provides following data:

```
[
    {
       "id": 4007,
       "name": "Curitiba, Paraná, BR"
    },
    {
       "id": 4391,
       "name": "Curitibanos, Santa Catarina, BR"
    }

]
```

But I need format this data using JavaScript in something that looks like:

```
{ 
  "Curitiba, Paraná, BR": null,
  "Curitibanos, Santa Catarina, BR" , null
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your array of objects to an array of `{[name]: null}` objects. Here `[name]` is a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), which allows you to use the value of the `name` variable as the key for your object. You can then merge the mapped array into one resulting object using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) along with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`).

See example below:

```js
const arr= [ { "id": 4007, "name": "Curitiba, Paraná, BR" }, { "id": 4391, "name": "Curitibanos, Santa Catarina, BR" } ];

const res = Object.assign(...arr.map(({name}) => ({[name]: null})));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do for this is to assign each name as a key in a new object:

```js
const data = [
    {
       "id": 4007,
       "name": "Curitiba, Paraná, BR"
    },
    {
       "id": 4391,
       "name": "Curitibanos, Santa Catarina, BR"
    }

];

var object = {};
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    object[data[i].name] = null;
};

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Awesome answer, Works like a charm, for me that are so not skilled with Javascript, that allowed me to clear see the logic behind operation. Anyway, in console looks like its returning Curitiba, Paraná, BR: null instead "Curitiba, Paraná, BR": null is this only a formating by inspector or this is expected? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you :) I think that's just formatting - you can prove it to yourself by doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(object));`. As well as being clearer to understand, simply using a `for` loop is also more efficient than these newer in-built functions (no function calls needed), so this typically seems like the best practice.